# Why do some categories change when I save an spss file as csv and read it again in spss?

Tags: csv, spss

I have a large spss file (.sav) and saved it as a .csv file. This file is too big to open in Excel, so I read this file again in spss. However, there are now some cases that for certain variables have dates instead of the categories of the original file. I didn't change anything in the file itself, so how is it possible that the content of some variables changes for a only a small number of cases?

Comment: When importing a text file into SPSS you have the option of defining the type for each of the imported fields (otherwise SPSS decides for itself and can sometimes guess wrong). Make sure as you import the data that the problematic fields have the right type defined. If this doesn't solve your problem, please edit the post and add a sample of the data - the original and the imported (and changed) version.

Comment: Thank you, it turns out that the problem is solved if I specify the format of all the variables by hand!

Answer (score 1):

This issue here may be that the IBM SPSS Statistics Import data interface uses the GET DATA command syntax with variable formats defined as AUTO.

What happens is that the product actually reads the data twice, but only pastes the GET DATA command syntax from the first pass -- showing AUTO for all defined fields.  In the latest release (IBM SPSS Statistics 26.0) the /MAP subcommand now supplies you with the /VARIABLES= subcommand and the variable definitions SPSS Statistics actually used to read the data.

Going forward, you can reliably read the same text files in the same way by using the pasted GET DATA command syntax (with your own alterations).

For example:
The File -> Import Data interface gives the following output to the Output Viewer window

```
PRESERVE. 
SET DECIMAL DOT. 

GET DATA  /TYPE=TXT 
  /FILE="/Applications/IBMSPSSStatistics/Subscription/Samples/English/demo.txt" 
  /ENCODING='UTF8' 
  /DELIMITERS="\t" 
  /QUALIFIER='"' 
  /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED 
  /FIRSTCASE=2 
  /DATATYPEMIN PERCENTAGE=95.0 
  /VARIABLES= 
  Age AUTO 
  Gender AUTO 
  MaritalStatus AUTO 
  Address AUTO 
  Income AUTO 
  IncomeCategory AUTO 
  JobCategory AUTO 
  /MAP. 
RESTORE. 
CACHE. 
EXECUTE. 

Data written to the working file. 
7 variables and 200 cases written. 
Variable: Age                Type: Number  Format : F2 
Variable: Gender             Type: String  Format : A4 
Variable: MaritalStatus      Type: Number  Format : F1         One or more values were set to system-missing. 
Variable: Address            Type: Number  Format : F2 
Variable: Income             Type: Number  Format : F6.2 
Variable: IncomeCategory     Type: Number  Format : F4.2 
Variable: JobCategory        Type: Number  Format : F1 

Substitute the following to build syntax for these data. 
  /VARIABLES= 
   Age F2 
   Gender A4 
   MaritalStatus F1 
   Address F2 
   Income F6.2 
   IncomeCategory F4.2 
   JobCategory F1 

DATASET NAME DataSet1 WINDOW=FRONT.
```

If you were to replace the /VARIABLES subcommand with the suggested content, you could reliably read this data in the same way each time.

Thus:

```
PRESERVE. 
SET DECIMAL DOT. 

GET DATA  /TYPE=TXT 
  /FILE="/Applications/IBMSPSSStatistics/Subscription/Samples/English/demo.txt" 
  /ENCODING='UTF8' 
  /DELIMITERS="\t" 
  /QUALIFIER='"' 
  /ARRANGEMENT=DELIMITED 
  /FIRSTCASE=2 
  /DATATYPEMIN PERCENTAGE=95.0 
  /VARIABLES= 
   Age F2 
   Gender A4 
   MaritalStatus F1 
   Address F2 
   Income F6.2 
   IncomeCategory F4.2 
   JobCategory F1   
  /MAP. 
RESTORE. 
CACHE. 
EXECUTE.
```